# Cannot choose method from group in Task.FromAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have the following function

```
public static Task<int> SendTaskAsync(this Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags flags)
{
    AsyncCallback nullOp = (i) => { };
    IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, flags, nullOp, socket);
    // Use overload that takes an IAsyncResult directly
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, socket.EndSend);
}
```

However I'm getting a

> "Cannot choose method from group"

error on FromAsync. How should my code be? I'm pretty new to TAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
 return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, socket.EndSend);
```

into this:

```
 return  Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(result, socket.EndSend);
```

Edit:

As @cremor says, you can alternatively use:

```
 return Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(result, socket.EndSend);
```

Comment: Alternatively specify the generic parameter on the `FromAsync` method instead. That would be more logical in my opinion.